# Updating the same data in a cluster may cause coverage issues

Tags: django, web, concurrency, cluster-computing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGzrV.png)As shown in the  figure when different servers in my web cluster operate on the same data, it may result in data coverage. How should I handle this problem?

I know that if there is only one server, locking this part in the business logic is sufficient, but now it is a service cluster, locking cannot limit this behavior

Or how should we set up reasonable logic in the face of this situation

I have tried to set an inaccessible identifier for the current data when operating on the front-end page. But the same problem occurred when setting identifiers

My backend service uses Django, and for a single server, I use with transaction. atomic() to prevent problems from occurring

If it's a server cluster, I'm not sure what to do. I have little experience in this area. Can someone help me